# Unable to install gflags on Babun(cygwin)

Tags: software-installation, cygwin, google

Despite manually resolving most of the dependencies, I haven't yet been able to successfully install one of the google libraries [`gflags`](https://github.com/gflags/gflags) on `Babun`.

I've been following [this](https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/INSTALL.md), and stuck at `mkdir build && cd build`, which wouldn't work as the **File** `BUILD` already exists in the directory.

```
{ gflags } master » mkdir build && cd build
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘build’: File exists
```

Any clue to move further is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See "Case sensitive filenames" on

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html

You need to tell windows to be case sensitive ;-)